# Mocking constructor callback

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, mocking, jestjs

I'm writing unit tests for an AudioPlayer class that uses [react-native-sound](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sound), so I'm trying to mock `react-native-sound` using a manual mock inside the `__mocks__` folder. Here's the mocked class:

```
export default class Sound {
  _filename = null;
  _basePath = null;
  _duration = -1;
  _currentTime = 0;
  _volume = 1;
  _loaded = false;

  constructor(filename, basePath, callback) {
    this._filename = filename;
    this._basePath = basePath;
    this._duration = 500;
    this._loaded = true;

    callback();
  }

  static setCategory = (value, mixWithOthers) => {};
  static setMode = value => {};
  static setActive = value => {};

  isLoaded = () => { return this._loaded; };
  getDuration = () =>  { return this._duration; };
  getCurrentTime = callback => {
    callback(this._currentTime);
  };
  getVolume = () => { return this._volume; };
  setVolume = value => {
    this._volume = value;
  };
}
```

The AudioPlayer class has a load method with an optional parameter for the volume, like the following:

```
export default class AudioPlayer {
  loaded = false;
  load = (path: string, volume: number = 1) => {
    const that = this;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const sound = new Sound(path, "", error => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        } else {
          sound.setVolume(volume); // <----- Fail here
          loaded = true;
          resolve();
        }
      });
    });
  };
```

And, here's what I'm trying in the unit test:

```
jest.mock("react-native-sound");

describe("audio-player", () => {
  it("can load audio file", () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    const audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
    const path = "sample_audio.mp3";
    return audioPlayer.load(path).then(() => {
      expect(audioPlayer.loaded).toEqual(true);
    });
  });
});
```

But, this fails with the following error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setVolume' of undefined

And, that's because the code that tries to set the volume is inside the constructor, and for whatever reason, the mocked class is still undefined inside the constructor. How do I make that work? How can I make a constructor with a callback function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I just put the call to the callback function inside the constructor inside a 2000 millisecond time-out:

```
constructor(filename, basePath, callback) {
    this._filename = filename;
    this._basePath = basePath;
    this._duration = 500;
    this._loaded = true;

    setTimeout(() => {
        callback();
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, was struggling with the same issue. For me a timeout of 0 ms was already enough.